# CSS animations transitioning from behind other elements broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/enfvL4d9/1/) a simple example of what I mean.

HTML

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="ht-tx1"></div>
<div class="headtest"></div>
<div class="ht-tx2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 250px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.headtest {
    font-family: 'quicksand', helvetica;
    background-color: #a2aba2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.ht-tx1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #000;
     animation: test-ani1 2s forwards;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
}

.ht-tx2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    animation: test-ani2 2s forwards;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}



@keyframes test-ani1 {

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}

@keyframes test-ani2 {

    100% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}
```

-

If you view in Chrome, both black bars slide out perfectly. The one transitioning from behind, and the one in front.

If you view it in Firefox, the bar transitioning from behind is broken. It sometimes works, but mostly it ignores the slide animation and just appears at the end of the animation duration.

I've re-created this a number of times and it seems that items that transition from behind another element are broken in firefox.

I've tried using -moz- which doesn't work. IS there anything else you can think of?

I've tried it without the absolute positioning, with z-indexs. and nothing seems to work.

EDIT ----

### I appreciate work-around ideas, but I'd really like to know the route cause of this if anyone knows?

Thanks very much.

Comment: It is a fact that FF does that, so is my answer to your satisfaction or you need something more?

Comment: Yours is a fix, but I'd like to understand the route cause it possible. I've updated my initial post to reflect this.

Comment: I google it in so many ways and came up empty, so most likely a bug. At the end of they day you hopefully have better use of a workaround than an official bug report, assuming you need to create the effect of course.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Firefox is inconsistent when animate the `transform` property, and I can't say why (yet), most likely a bug though.

Here is 2 workarounds to achieve the same effect

```css
.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.headtest {
    font-family: 'quicksand', helvetica;
    background-color: #a2aba2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.ht-tx1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #000;
     animation: test-ani1 2s forwards;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
}

.ht-tx2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    animation: test-ani2 2s forwards;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}



@keyframes test-ani1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-1px);
    }
    0.1% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}

@keyframes test-ani2 {
    100% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="ht-tx1"></div>
<div class="headtest"></div>
<div class="ht-tx2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.headtest {
  font-family: 'quicksand', helvetica;
  background-color: #a2aba2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.ht-tx1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: test-ani1 2s forwards;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.ht-tx2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: test-ani2 2s forwards;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}


@keyframes test-ani1 {
  100% {
    top: -20px;
  }
}

@keyframes test-ani2 {
  100% {
    height: 20px;
    bottom: -20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="ht-tx1"></div>
  <div class="headtest"></div>
  <div class="ht-tx2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution relies on the z-index property of your elements: if you don't specify it the elements lay out one on top of the others, following the flow of the HTML document, when their "position" is set to "absolute". So "ht-txt1" is underneath "headtest" and "ht-tx2" is on top of "headtest".

To correct this "ht-tx1" and "ht-tx2" should take a "z-index" value of -1, so they are hidden underneath "headtest".

As for FF compatibility you need to prefix your "transform" effect with -moz-, check http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d for more details.

Here's the CSS style code:

```
    .main-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 250px 0 0 0;
        position: relative;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .headtest {
        font-family: 'quicksand', helvetica;
        background-color: #a2aba2;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .ht-tx1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
         text-align: center;
         background-color: #000;
         animation: test-ani1 2s forwards;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         z-index: -1;
    }

    .ht-tx2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000;
        animation: test-ani2 2s forwards;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    @keyframes test-ani1 {

        100% {
            -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
            -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
            transform: translateY(-20px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes test-ani2 {

        100% {
            -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
            -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
            transform: translateY(20px);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you test this in FF? ... I did and it still has the animation issue. Furthermore, FF dropped the `moz` prefix a few years ago.

Comment: You're right for the -moz- prefix part. Tested it straight on FF, not through jsfiddle and worked fine. Under jsfiddle the issue is not solved... Weird...Using FF 44.0.2

Comment: After looking at this again, I got the same behavior as @Zakalwe mentionned, it sometimes works. Looks like the browser processes the hidden element events in a lower priority than the visible ones. So your solution is a welcome workaround.